# How do I change this variable in my jquery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jquery audio recording plugin jrecorder and I want to be able to change the audio file name by pushing a button.  The script defines the file name with the 'host' variable.  I want to be able to change that variable to "track01" by clicking button01 or "track02" by clicking button2.  How would I go about doing this?

```
   <script>

   $.jRecorder(

 { 
    host : 'acceptfile.php?filename=track00' , 

    callback_started_recording:     function(){callback_started(); },
    callback_stopped_recording:     function(){callback_stopped(); },
    callback_activityLevel:          function(level){callback_activityLevel(level); },
    callback_activityTime:     function(time){callback_activityTime(time); },

    callback_finished_sending:     function(time){ callback_finished_sending() },


    swf_path : 'jRecorder.swf',

 });

 ////Make buttons change save-file name 
 $("#button01").click(function(){

    //CHANGE 'host' to 'acceptfile.php?filename=track01'
;});


$("#button02").click(function(){

    //CHANGE 'host' to 'acceptfile.php?filename=track02'
  ;});

    </script>
```

Comment: Something tells me that when the object with settings is passed to the plugin, it's to late to change it.

Comment: Instead of this question, you should be doing a Javascript tutorial, as this isn't any particular kind of bug at all, I think you just need to learn some basics first.

Comment: I am facing the same issue!! did you find any solution, if yes, please post! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to devise the solution by making changes in the Main.as script file and also in the jRecorder.js file. Following are **six** steps that you will need to achieve this.

***Step -1***
Go to https://github.com/sythoos/jRecorder and download everything in the flash-fla folder. Make sure you match the folder of the flash-fla folder structure EXACTLY on your local machine.

***Step -2***
Once you have done that, and if you haven't got it already, you're going to need to download Flash. I used the free 30 day trial to do this, you can also do the same.

***Step 3. Open `Main.as` file and make following two changes:***

- Change : 1

  Define a new string variable to contain file name
- Change : 2

  Add parameter in "jSendFileToServer" method

***Step 4:*** Once the above changes are done,  you need to open up the AudioRecorderCS4-1.0.fla file in Flash and export the movie (File -> Export -> Export Movie).

***Step 5. Open jRecorder.js file and make following change:***

Add parameter to sendData Method

***Step 6. Open your HTML and make the change in the JS method which calls sendData***

Add parameter in the sendData Method

Following are the code snippets, please note that I am pasting few lines of code before and after my changes by adding comments to the code which I have added/modified.

**Main.as File**

```
private var recorder:MicRecorder = new MicRecorder(waveEncoder);
private var recBar:RecBar = new RecBar();

private var maxTime:Number = 30;
//Start of addition by FaisalKhan
private var FileName:String = 'Hello.wav';
//End of addition by FaisalKhan


    
//Start of change 1 of 2 by Faisal
//public function jSendFileToServer():void
public function jSendFileToServer(file_name):void
//End of change 1 of 2 by Faisal
{
    //Start of change 2 of 2 by FaisalKhan
    FileName=file_name;
    //End of change 2 of 2 by FaisalKhan
    finalize_recording();
    
}
        
//functioon send data to server
private function finalize_recording():void
{
    
    var _var1:String= '';
    
    var globalParam = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
    for (var element:String in globalParam) {
    if (element == 'host'){
        //Start of change by FaisalKhan
        //_var1 =   globalParam[element];
        _var1 =   globalParam[element]+FileName;
        //End  of change by FaisalKhan
        }
    }
    
    
    ExternalInterface.call("$.jRecorder.callback_finished_recording");
    
    if(_var1 != '')
    {
        var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(_var1);
        req.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
        req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        req.data = recorder.output;
        
        
    
        
        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(req);
        ExternalInterface.call("$.jRecorder.callback_finished_sending");
    
    }
    
}
```

**jRecorder.js file change:**

```
//function call to send wav data to server url from the init configuration                  
//Start of change by FaisalKhan
//$.jRecorder.sendData = function(){
$.jRecorder.sendData = function(file_name){
    //getFlashMovie(jRecorderSettings['recorder_name']).jSendFileToServer();                
    getFlashMovie(jRecorderSettings['recorder_name']).jSendFileToServer(file_name);
//End of change by FaisalKhan                           
}
```

**HTML Button click method change:**

```
$('#SendRecordingDiv').click(function(){
    //Start of change by FaisalKhan
    //$.jRecorder.sendData($();
    $.jRecorder.sendData($("#FileControl").val()+'.wav');
    //End of change by FaisalKhan
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is how, although I think you will still have issues because your $.jRecorder code is running as soon as the page loads, so by the time a user hits a button its too late.  Maybe also consider putting that inside a function, and calling that function after they press the button.

```
<script>


function WhoSaysDearMe(saveFileName) {

   $.jRecorder({ 

    host : saveFileName , 

    callback_started_recording:     function(){callback_started(); },
    callback_stopped_recording:     function(){callback_stopped(); },
    callback_activityLevel:          function(level){callback_activityLevel(level); },
    callback_activityTime:     function(time){callback_activityTime(time); },

    callback_finished_sending:     function(time){ callback_finished_sending() },


    swf_path : 'jRecorder.swf',

   });
}

 ////Make buttons change save-file name 
 $("#button01").click(function(){

    //CHANGE 'host' to 'acceptfile.php?filename=track01'
    WhoSaysDearMe('acceptfile.php?filename=track01');
;});


$("#button02").click(function(){

    //CHANGE 'host' to 'acceptfile.php?filename=track02'
    WhoSaysDearMe('acceptfile.php?filename=track02');
  ;});

</script>
```

Comment: you are encouraging a new Javascript developer to use global variables... dear me.

Comment: sorry bout that.. fixed

Comment: Thanks erik, but it didn't work. I think adeneo above was right, too late to change it at that point.  dc2, thanks for being a smug db rather than providing anything constructive.

Comment: it was too late because you were initializing it on load, but in my example i changed it to happen when the button was clicked.  Which part is still not working?